# Draw Perpendicular to a line

Tags: tkz-euclide

Compile this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[
a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,headheight=14.5pt,]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0:0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0:6){B}
\tkzDefPoint(45:4){C}
\tkzDefPoint(0:3){D}

\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.8mm](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.8mm](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](D){$D$}

\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,A)
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,D)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,D,A)
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

You will see the line segment CD is not perpendicular to AB that is the problem.
So what is the solution to this?

Comment: You defined where `D` is, and that is _not_  the correct point. Better to compute where that point should go: `\pgfmathsetmacro{\DLocation}{4*cos(45)}%
\tkzDefPoint(0:\DLocation){D}` resolves the issue.

Comment: Sorry to say, but i don't get sir what you are saying.

Answer (score 3):

As @Peter Grill has said, you calculated D incorrectly. The tangent of the 45 degree angle you constructed must be 1. So the side from C to D must have length 3, but then the sides of your triangle won't satisfy the Pythagorean Theorem since 3^2+3^2 is not equal to 4^2. You should be moving sqrt(18) along the 45 degree angle.

But the `tkz-euclide` package you're using has a macro to perform the calculation of the point and then another macro to name it:
\tkzDrawAltitude[color=black](A,B)(C)  will calculate the point that is the altitude for point C with respect to line segment (A,B) and
\tkzGetPoint{D} take the point and names it D, so you can use it. I've cleaned up your code and added some options you can fiddle with to get this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}%IMPORTANT in most tkz-euclide code
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=0,scale=2.0]%rotate picture 0 degrees
%choose the vertices of the triangle
\tkzDefPoint(0:0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0:6){B}
\tkzDefPoint(45:4){C}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.8mm](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.8mm](A){$A$}

\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,A)
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,B)

\tkzDrawAltitude[color=black](A,B)(C) 
\tkzGetPoint{D}%Get the point of intersection
\tkzLabelPoint[below](D){$D$}
\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,D,A)%Mark with a right angle symbol
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output running in Gummi:
[image]